# Update query returns wrong values

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have this function:

```
 virtual public bool EditVideoNumber(String oldnumber, String channelnumber)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText += "update Videos set number=REPLACE(number,@oldnumber,@channelnumber)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@channelnumber", channelnumber));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@oldnumber", oldnumber));
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, in the moment that i update the value oldnumber, from 102 to 1020 (just an example), it returns as a value 10200. i have tried to change the query several times, but nothing seems to make it work

Comment: The REPLACE function replaces a part of a string. So if there are records with a number '9102' then you will replace them also. Is this the intended behavior? Or do you need a where condition? (in which case you probably don't need the replace function in the first place)

Comment: "it returns as a value 10200" - what do you mean by this? Your query doesn't returns anything, it is just update.

Comment: @codemonkey i figure it out in the moment i posted the question. it needed a where condition for the update to take place in the program, even though the query in sql server manager was working fine. Thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This will replace your current number value, with an other value with 0 appended at the end:

```
cmd.CommandText += "update Videos set number=REPLACE(number,number,CONTACT(number,'0'))";
```